# Days Difference between current and an up coming Date in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have tried so many things through the help I got, but I still can't figure out how to do it properly. Here's what I did lastly.

```
NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyy"];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *fromDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]];
NSLog(@"currentDate %@", fromDate);

NSDate *toDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
NSLog(@"toDate %@", toDate);

NSTimeInterval interval = [toDate timeIntervalSinceDate:fromDate];
double leftDays = interval/86400;
NSLog(@"Total interval Between::%g",leftDays);
```

Tell me what I did wrong. Is it the NSDate conversion, that I am not doing properly ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is creating problem.

```
 NSDate *toDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
```

It changes the type of `toDate` from NSDate to `__NSCFString`. The `NSTimeInterval` take both of its arguments of NSDate type, but in your case only `fromDate` is NSDate type.

Change your code with these lines

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *toDate = datePicker.date;
NSTimeInterval interval = [toDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
```

It will surely work (inshaAllah).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is all messed up -- both toDate and fromDate are strings not NSDates. Your from date should just be currentDate, and your toDate should just be datePicker.date. You don't need to do anything with converting to strings or using a date formatter to get the time interval.

Answer (score 1):

You're certainly on the right track; however, you seem to be calling "timeIntervalSinceDate" using two NSString's (even though you're specifying fromDate and toDate as NSDates, look right after that- you're setting those two variables to NSString objects).

To get the interval you're looking for, try:

```
[datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
```

That should get you the right interval. In addition, you may want to change leftDays to equal

```
double leftDays = abs(round(interval/86400));
```

This will stop leftDays from being an awkward number like -1.00005.

Answer (score 1):

`Passing NSString to NSDate! this code is wrong

try

```
NSDate *curDate = [NSDate Date];
NSDate *pickerDate = datepicker.date;
```

then compare both these dates using NSTimeInterval